# Store the file body without interrupting the route

Tags: apache-camel

Basically I have route like following.

```
    from("servlet://test/?matchOnUriPrefix=true&servletName=testservlet")
            .log("Wire tap beginning")
            .streamCaching()
            .wireTap("seda:tap").copy(true).end()
            .log("End of wiretap")
            .log("request sent to provider ")
            .to("https://someservice.com" + "?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false")
            .log("request sent to END");
```

Above route redirects the request to "https://someservice.com".

"https://someservice.com" request is 'Post' call which accepts 
- text/plain; charset=UTF-8
- gzip file body

My intentions is to save the gzip body without interrupting the actual route. My intention of using 'wiretap' was to achieve the same i.e. save the request body in a separate thread.

When I make a request, I don't see 'https://someservice.com' is getting invoked in a separate thread, basically the execution happens in following way.

1.wiretap endpoint is invoked first, once after wiretap ("seda:tap") processing is finished then
2."https://someservice.com" is invoked.

Adding code of seda:wiretap

```
    from("seda:tap")
            .unmarshal().gzip()
            .to("seda:storedata");

    from("seda:storedata")
            .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    //store the data
                    Message message = exchange.getIn();
                    String result=message.getBody(String.class);
                }});
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Tell seda to not wait for reply

```
.wireTap("seda:tap?waitForTaskToComplete=Never").copy(true).end()
```

- http://camel.apache.org/seda

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work :( i.e. .to("https://someservice.com" + "?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false") didn't got executed till 'seda:tap' got completed.